# Bathroom fan replacement, non-standard plug

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

A couple of nights ago, I noticed that my bathroom exhaust had stopped working. It still makes a humming sound but it doesn't spin, so I assumed it's probably the motor.

I removed the motor/fan and then looked for a replacement online. The sticker with the model name has scratched off, although I can see from the cover that it's a Stelpro. Unfortunately, all the potential replacements I have seen connect to a standard power outlet, whereas the one I have has the below connector (Google tells me it's called a Tamiya connector).

Is it possible to buy a replacement, or would I need to replace the whole unit? If it's the latter, is that something that I would be able to do myself? For reference, my electrical experience is limited to installing a couple of dimmer switches.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: And since it's an AC motor, it shouldn't matter which wire is which.  The problem here might be finding a motor whose shaft matches, and swapping the fan from one to the other.

Comment: Looks to be a Stelpro SBF, discontinued. https://www.stelpro.com/en/products/bathroom-exhaust-fan-sbf/

Have you contacted Stelpro to see if they offer a replacement part?

Comment: @huesmann Thanks, I'll try this first

Comment: Do you have access from above, or is there living space above?

Comment: We have an attic, but I don't think there's any floorboards.

Comment: Doesn't matter if there aren't floorboards, you can rig something temporary.  If you can't find a direct replacement for the motor, you can replace the whole unit.  There's bound to be *something* out there close enough in dimensions.

Comment: Stelpro say they have stopped making exhaust fans. I'll try the attic solution when I have the time.

Answer (score 0):

Why replace it? All that lint is likely the only issue, keeping the motor from turning.

- Remove the two Phillips-head screws holding the bearing, noting the order of any washers on the screws and shaft.
- Remove the squirrel-cage fan, if the setscrew is not frozen by corrosion.
- Clean all surfaces thoroughly with a toothbrush and **mild** solvent, such as 91% or stronger isopropanol (flammable) and allow to dry **thoroughly**. One could even use *some* water, but drying time would be much extended. **Be very gentle** in cleaning around the motor winding (covered in plastic) and attached wires.
- Put just a drop or two of ordinary motor oil (e.g., 5W-30) on the shaft at each end, and on any felt around the two shaft bearings.
- Reassemble and check that the fan turns freely.

That bathroom fan should run as well, and last as long, as a new one.

Comment: I'm not so sure. I clean my fans regularly, and they often look like that or worse, and they never actually bind up. There's no real resistance in the motor caused by surface lint.

Comment: I'll try cleaning it and see if that helps.

Comment: I've had one genuinely fail. It happens.